# Local variable in Python list display

Tags: python, syntax, coding-style, list-comprehension

I want a local binding inside a Python list or dictionary display expression, so that I can use the result of a complicated expression in several places (for instance, an if-clause and in the resulting member expression).  Like this:

```
traders = {a:b
           for g in groups
           for a in account.group_accounts(g)
           for b in [account.accounts[a].balance().get_amount()]
           if my_condition(b)}
```

but to achieve it I've had to make a singleton list, which is ugly and unclear.  I really want to say

```
           where b = account.accounts[a].balance().get_amount()
```

but Python display syntax doesn't allow anything like this.  What's the best syntax for this purpose?

Comment: what about re-writing this mess in a plain old readable loop ?

Comment: Is `account` an instance of a class ?

Comment: While you can probably find some hacky way of using functions with side effects to make something like this work, you really shouldn't.  Python has some functional constructs, but it isn't a functional language.  If you want code like this to be readable, you have to write it in an imperative style, i.e. plain for loops.

Comment: I don't understand any of those comments.  This is a plain readable loop (in fact, two of them, nested) in a dictionary display expression.  What I want is a recommendation for the best way to express the binding of `b` in the `for b in ...` line.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the singleton list in your original post is the neatest way to do what you want while keeping the code in a single expression.

Proposals to add some syntax for binding variables in a comprehension come up from time to time on the python-ideas mailing list. [Here's one from Lie Ryan](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2009-June/004946.html) in 2009, and [here's one from Mathias Panzenböck](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-April/009797.html) in 2011. The usual objections are unnecessary complexity:

> The lack of local assignment is a feature. It keeps people from trying
>   to write overly complex one-liners. ([Carl M. Johnson](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-April/009812.html))

and loss of readability:

> `[y for x in xs given f(x) if p(x) else g(x) as y]` — Is it just me, or do others find this "string of clauses" (no matter what the actual keywords are) not very readable? ([Georg Brandl](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2011-April/009864.html))

Answer (score -1):

To implement

```
accounts[a].balance().get_amount()
```

you can do something like this

```
class Balance(object):
    def __init__(self, money):
        self.money = money
    def get_amount(self):
        return self.money

class Accounts(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.accounts = list()
    def add(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_account = Account(*args, **kwargs)
        self.accounts.append(new_account)
        return new_account
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self.accounts[item]

class Account(object):
    accounts = []
    def __init__(self, name, money):
        self.name = name
        self.balance = Balance(money)

accounts = Accounts()
accounts.add(name="1", money=42)
accounts.add(name="2", money=24)
accounts.add(name="3", money=33)

print accounts[0].balance.get_amount()
```

will print

```
42
```

Python implements many programming paradigms not only imperative so you should watch at libraries like pandas and sqlalchemy with the same syntax.

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that.  Indeed, I have a few hundred lines of code in other modules doing stuff like that.  That's not what this question is about.  What I want is a style recommendation for use _inside_a_list_or_dictionary_display_expression_, in place of the `for b in ...` line in my above sample.